counting items in a column with comma separated lists and ordering them
I have a Google Sheet with a column of comma separated lists for example:

atl hip hop, dirty south rap, hip hop
atl hip hop, hip hop, rap
canadian hip hop, canadian pop, hip hop

I need help creating a formula to count unique items across all the lists and order them by count. Thanks!
I found this from another post:
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",",A:A),",")&{"";""}),"select Col1, count(Col2) group by Col1 label count(Col2) ''",0))
It counts the unique items but I don't know how to use "order by" to order the results by Col2.

Using the formula you provided, here is how you add the order by clause (here, in descending order):
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",",A:A),",")&{"";""}),"select Col1, count(Col2) group by Col1 order by count(Col2) desc label count(Col2) ''",0))

You can read more about query syntax here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#language-clauses

thanks, this worked great! i now also want to limit the results to 10. but I cant find where to put "limit 10"

after order by and before label. e.g., =ArrayFormula(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",",A:A),",")&{"";""}),"select Col1, count(Col2) group by Col1 order by count(Col2) desc limit 10 label count(Col2) ''",0))

Another solution:
=SORT(LET(a,TOCOL(SPLIT(A:A,", ",),3),u,UNIQUE(a),{u,COUNTIF(a,u)}),2,0)


this works great to. thanks for the alternative option.
